# How can I make text appear when hovering a picture that has already the hovering for transform?

Tags: html, css

**HTML**

```
<div class="feature" >
<img src="0308_WVenvirophotos1-water-pollutions.jpg" 
width="100%" height="100%"/></div>
```

**CSS**

```
.feature{

height:50%;
width: 60%;
float: left;
margin: 0.5%;
-webkit-transition: width 1s, height 1s, -webkit-transform 2s; 
transition: width 1s, height 1s, transform 2s; 
}

.feature:hover{

width: 800px;
height: 520px;
-webkit-transform: translate(,) ; 
transform: translate(,);
}
```

This code makes the picture larger when hovered.  How can I make the text appear on hover as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the pseudo element [:before](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::before), you can do something like this:

```
.feature:hover:before {
  content:'Text Goes Here';
  font-size:20px;
  color:white;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;    
}
```

Essentially, we're adding the text to the element on hover by using the content property of :before .

Checkout a fiddle showing that here: http://jsfiddle.net/34p5xqmL/

Comment: how can i make a paragraph in my content?

Comment: i figured it out with width

Comment: Great, for future people with a similar question--it would help to leave a fiddle showing your solution. Also please be sure to mark this as the answer if it was helpful in answering your question.